# how to get the documents info using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my reactjs application How to get the Document full info in JavaScript, example if I am using the .pdf or .doc file I need to know the page count. is it possible in JavaScript? I tried with `react-file-viewer` i can preview the doc but there is no way to get the doc info in that package. Is there any other way to do this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import FileViewer from 'react-file-viewer';
import './App.css';

class Pdf extends Component {
    render() {
        const file = 'https://web.stanford.edu/group/csp/cs21/htmlcheatsheet.pdf';
        const type = 'pdf';
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <FileViewer
                    fileType={type}
                    filePath={file}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Pdf;
```

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far

Comment: For reading PDF info in browser, you can try https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

Comment: @GanapatiVS Not only pdf it may be .doc, csv, xslx

Comment: @HasanEmrahSüngü I added the code what I tried

Comment: Any solution @HasanEmrahSüngü

Comment: check the `file.type` and use respective library for reading in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below javaScript/jQuery Code, which is working for PDF.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="btn btn bg-primary">
        <input type="file" id="fileBrowse"/>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div id="page"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

    //Image Upload Preview
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#fileBrowse").change(function () {
              readImage(this);
        })

    })
    function readImage(input) {

      if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsBinaryString(input.files[0]);
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                var count = reader.result.match(/\/Type[\s]*\/Page[^s]/g).length;
                $("#page").html('Number of Pages:'+count);
            }
      }
    }
</script>
```